# Plancherel's theorem clarification

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Folland states Plancherel's theorem as follows: If $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$ then $\widehat{f} \in L^2$ and $\mathcal{F} | (L^1 \cap L^2)$ extends uniquely to a unitary isomorphism on $L^2$ where $\mathcal{F}$ stands for Schwartz functions.

I know we obtain Parseval's identity from this there, i.e $$ ||f||_2 = || \widehat{f}||_2$$ However, I am not entirely sure what is the significance of a unitary isomorphism.

For example, if $f \in \mathcal{H} \subset L^2$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is some closed subspace of the Hilbert space $L^2$ If I find a basis for the fourier transforms $\widehat{f} \in L^2$, how does this related to a basis for $\mathcal{H}$?

Sorry if the above is confusing. I am just not sure as to how to interpret the significance of Plancherel's theorem.

Comment: A linear isometry preserves length (and distances, hence iso-metry): $\|Lf\|=\|f\|$ for all $f$. For a complex inner product space $L$ being an isometry is equivalent to $L^{\star}L=I$. However, that does not mean $LL^{\star}=I$. An isometry on a Hilbert space which is also surjective is called unitary, which is where $L^{\star}L=LL^{\star}=I$. The right shift operator on $l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ is an isometry which is not unitary. The Fourier transform is unitary on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1):

Unitary means it preserves the inner product so "unitary isomorphism" is a fancy way of saying that the Fourier transform is an isometry of $L^2$.

Morally, Plancherel's theorem says that you can think of the Fourier transform as like a 'rotation' of $L^2$. It preserves distances and angles, as measured by the $L^2$ inner product.